# python 2.7 socket.send() general contract

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

Could somebody please explain to me general contract of python's socket.send() method?
I am making some kind of a traffic generator as a part of an educational project.

I do simple logging whenever socket.send() method executes, i send some traffic and write down to file the time when the method finished ( among other things i log). These logs show that i sent more messages then the wireshark shows, this happens when my outgoing traffic gets relatively high.

I have read:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto

As mentioned in the link i provided: ' They do not necessarily handle all the bytes you hand them (or expect from them), because their major focus is handling the network buffers. In general, they return when the associated network buffers have been filled (send)'.

If i understod correctly, there is no guarantee that my message will acctualy be sent. I can read how many bytes socket.send() **handled**, but i would like to know what excatly does it mean by 'handled'.

Can somebody explain to me:

- what is network buffer in the link i provided ( TCP window, some kind of queue on my network card, something else ? )
- layman's terms, how is socket.send() implemented in python so that i can utilize it   better. How does it interact with my hardware/OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using TCP, the network layer *does* guarantee that all the bytes you pass to `send()` will actually be sent (if not, the socket will be closed). However, it sounds like you are counting packets rather than bytes.

There is not always a relationship between the number of times you call `send()` and the number of packets that are sent. The network layer is free to consolidate or split the data you pass to `send()` into differently sized packets, as long as it all finds its way to the remote end in the same order it was sent.

If you want more control over the *number* of packets that are sent, use UDP instead of TCP.

Comment: I am counting packets indeed. I mentioned bytes because docs mention bytes so im trying to understand what these bytes represent. Can method send() then translate to less packets than there are calls of send? If you are talking about fragmentation, would it not be the oposite ? I would have more packets in wireshark than i have called method send() ? Also, i have to use TCP at transport layer. I didnt know these packets could be consolidated too

Comment: Fragmentation is an even lower level thing. For TCP, check out  [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) (the TCP layer does this for you). You can turn off nagling, but that still doesn't guarantee that your packets won't be split or combined. TCP is a stream-based service and the network packets are not relevant to its users.

Comment: This is very useful information. However, the package size i send is not less than 200B and acording to your reference my packets shouldn't be in that category? I have Diameter protocol packages that i send using the TCP at transport layer.

Comment: Again, TCP makes no guarantees about how your data is combined into packets. Turning off nagling gives TCP a *hint* that you would like better interactive response, but the TCP layer can still do what it wants as long as the resulting stream at the receiver is the same as what you send.